# call sequence of events in listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

How to understand when, after Changed work will call Click?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" SelectionChanged="Changed">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Click" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: please can you explain more clearly what do you expect to get?

Comment: @Ilan . After first load and select listviewitem call Changed then Click, when i select other  listviewitem  call only Changed

Comment: do you select using mouse or by keyboard arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Event "Changed" will be called when Mouse left button is down and "Click" will be called when you leave Mouse Left Button. (An Item is selected in list view when MouseLeftButton is down.)

"Click" is action done through Mouse, but selecteditem will be called after listview is populated.